# 'RadioSelect' object has no attribute 'renderer'

Tags: python, django

I have made a web site by seeing django tutorial.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/

I got an error,

```
AttributeError at /polls/1/
'RadioSelect' object has no attribute 'renderer'
```

It happens in line 21 of forms.py,which is init.
I wrote in forms.py like

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False,label='テキスト')

class VoteForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=None,
        label='選択',
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        empty_label=None,
        error_messages={
            'required':"You didn't select a choice.",
            'invalid_choice':"invalid choice.",
        },
    )

    def __init__(self,question,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'].queryset = question.choice_set.all()
        self.fields['choice'].widget.renderer.inner_html = '{choice_value}{sub_widgets}<br>'
```

Setting of radio button is written in detail.html,like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'poll_vote' question.id %}" method="post">
<!--<form action="" method="post">-->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
    {% endfor %}
    <!--{{ form }}-->
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
</html>
```

views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from .models import Question
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,redirect
from .models import Choice
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .forms import MyForm
from .forms import VoteForm


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'polls/index.html',{
        'questions': Question.objects.all(),
    })

def detail(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VoteForm(question=obj,data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('polls:results',pk)
    else:
        form = VoteForm(question=obj)
    return render(request,'templates/polls/detail.html',{
        'form':form,
        'question': obj,
    })

def vote(request,pk):
    pass

def results(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'polls/results.html',{
        'question':obj,
    })

def form_test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #request.POST???
        form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request,'polls/form.html',{
        'form':form,
    })
```

Traceback is like

```
Traceback: File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner 35. response = get_response(request) File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response 130. response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) 
File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response 128. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Users/XXX/djangostudy/polls/views.py" in detail 40. form = VoteForm(question=obj) File "/Users/XXXi/djangostudy/polls/forms.py" in init 21. self.fields['choice'].widget.renderer.inner_html = '{choice_value}{sub_widgets}<br>' Exception Type: AttributeError at /polls/1/ Exception Value: 'RadioSelect' object has no attribute 'renderer'
```

I do not know how to fix it.I cannot understand why this error happen.
WHat should I do to fix this?

Comment: Include the complete traceback of the error in the question itself.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119037/what-will-be-the-alternative-for-forms-radioselect-renderer-in-new-version-of

Comment: You are calling `RadioSelect`, you shouldn't do that. Try `widget=forms.RadioSelect`, instead of `widget=forms.RadioSelect()`

Comment: `widgets={'type_id':forms.RadioSelect}` The widgets should actually represent widget.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil thx,ur comments.I fixed my code was like ur writing.But,same error happen.However,Traceback is different.It is like

Comment: Traceback:

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  130.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

Comment: File "/Users/XXX/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/XXX/djangostudy/polls/views.py" in detail
  40.         form = VoteForm(question=obj)

File "/Users/XXXi/djangostudy/polls/forms.py" in __init__
  21.         self.fields['choice'].widget.renderer.inner_html = '{choice_value}{sub_widgets}<br>'

Exception Type: AttributeError at /polls/1/
Exception Value: 'RadioSelect' object has no attribute 'renderer'

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil What should I do for next?

Comment: Edit the question and update it with latest code and latest traceback.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I updated my code&Traceback.If u know something,please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see what we have here:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> from myapp.models import Vote
>>> 
>>> class VoteForm(forms.Form):
...     choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(
...             queryset=Vote.objects.all(),
...             widget=forms.RadioSelect()
...     )
... 
>>> 
>>> f = VoteForm()
>>> 
>>> f.fields['choice']
<django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0xb64ec3ec>
>>>
>>> f.fields['choice'].widget.renderer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'RadioSelect' object has no attribute 'renderer'
>>>
```

You getting a traceback `AttributeError: 'RadioSelect' object has no attribute 'renderer'` because the `renderer` isn't available:

```
>>> dir(f.fields['choice'].widget)
['__class__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__',
'__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
'__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__',
'__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slotnames__', '__str__', 
'__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_format_value', '_render', 
'add_id_index', 'allow_multiple_selected', 'attrs', 'build_attrs',
'checked_attribute', 'choices', 'create_option', 'format_value',
'get_context', 'id_for_label', 'input_type', 'is_hidden', 'is_localized',
'is_required', 'media', 'needs_multipart_form', 'optgroups', 
'option_inherits_attrs', 'option_template_name', 'options', 'render',
'subwidgets', 'supports_microseconds', 'template_name',
'use_required_attribute', 'value_from_datadict', 'value_omitted_from_data']
>>>
```

But here we found `render` and `_render` functions:

```
>>> f.fields['choice'].widget.render
<bound method Widget.render of <django.forms.widgets.RadioSelect object at 0xb64ec4ac>>
>>> 
>>> f.fields['choices'].widget._render
<bound method Widget._render of <django.forms.widgets.RadioSelect object at 0xb64ec4ac>>
>>>
```

> I just don't know why you need this function `.inner_html`, and what expect to do.

Maybe this documentation about [customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) is useful for you.